# rc.local - not all commands are executed

Tags: linux, debian, startup

I have following lines in my rc.local

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

if [ -f /resize ]
then
if [ -f /resize2 ]
then
sh /resize2
else
sh /resize
fi
fi

/etc/rc --foreground
/sbin/iptables-restore /etc/iptables
mkdir /tmp/cooks
mkdir /tmp/cook
chmod 777 /tmp/cook
chmod 777 /tmp/cooks
mkdir /tmp/xhprof
chmod 777 /tmp/xhprof

exit 0
```

but neither `/tmp/cooks` nor `/tmp/cook` nor `/tmp/xhprof` dir was not created (on system startup).
I'm using `Debian GNU/Linux 6.0 squeeze (VPS)`

Comment: Is that the whole content of the file? There should be a `#!/bin/sh` line at the top. I notice Debian has `#!/bin/sh -e` by default and no `/etc/rc`, so the first line would fail and the script would exit. Is that what's happening?

Comment: edited question with whole content of rc.content

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The script begins with `#!/bin/sh -e`. The `-e` option means that the shell will exit if any command returns a nonzero status. It's likely that one of the commands is failing. Perhaps `/resize` or `/resize2` is returning nonzero, or perhaps `/etc/rc` is, or `iptables-restore`. Change the shebang line to `#!/bin/sh -ex` and run the script; you'll see a trace of the commands it executes.

If you find that one of the commands is returning nonzero when it should have succeeded, fix that. If you find that one of the commands is returning nonzero legitimately, add `|| true` after it. If you find that you don't care about the return status of any of the commands, remove the `-e`.

Comment: "vm645:/var/log/apache2# /etc/init.d/rc.local start
+ /sbin/iptables-restore /etc/iptables
+ mkdir /tmp/cooks
mkdir: adresář „/tmp/cooks“ nelze vytvořit: Soubor již existuje
vm645:/var/log/apache2#
" THANK YOU !